# Deep Linking with React Navigation and Redux Provider

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation, deep-linking

Can someone explain how to do deep linking using React Navigation while also using Redux?

I have searched for days and cannot find anything but very old details for React Navigation v1.

Is it supposed to just work by passing in the prefix, because if so, it isn't for me.

```
      const PREFIX = 'myApp://'

      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer uriPrefix={PREFIX} />
      </Provider>
```

I pass in all paths to each stack as described in instructions, but none ar working. I think it is because of the Provider redux store. Can someone help me who is aware of this issue?

Thanks!